# Make a list of values in one column, which do not exist in a second column

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet with two columns of data. Column A contains thousands of records, and Column B contains only a few records. I wish to identify which values in Column B do not exist in Column A, and display these in Column D. What is the quickest way to achieve this? Happy to use formulas, or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use conditional formatting and filters:

[image]

Formula being:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B,0))
```

I'd then filter on highlighted cells, select the cells in column A and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to select only the visible cells, then paste in D.

Last, I'd clear all the conditional formatting and clean up anything left.

---

Using formulae would be a little more complex; usually the most of the time would be spent designing it, and it's an array formula (invoked correctly only with Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$27,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$27)=0,ROW($A$2:$A$27),9^99),ROW(D1))),"")
```

The formula can also take some time to calculate for larger datasets.

[image]